# Update Environment Variables

Tags: python, django, linux, heroku

I'm in the process of porting my local django app to heroku and am hitting a snag. Mainly with my environment variables. I can't very well create a .env file on my webserver, it would just get overwritten when I push from github again. So I've set environment variables using `heroku config:set VAR='' --app <app>`. These seem to work, however, I'm working with an API that requires I refresh my token every 60 min. Locally, I developed a method to update my `.env` every time the task that refreshed this token was executed, but this solution clearly isn't sufficient for my web server...I've attempted to update server-level variables in Python, but I don't think that's possible. Has anyone had to deal with an issue like this? Am I approaching this all wrong?

What is the best way for me to update an environment variable on a web server (ie `heroku config:set VAR='' --app <app>` but in my python code)? I need this variable to update every 60 minutes (I already have the celery task code built for this). Should I modify the task to simply write it to a text file and use that text file as my "web server .env file"? I'm really lost here, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

As requested here's more information:

I'm building some middlware for two systems. The first system posts a record to my Django API. This event kicks off a task that subsequently updates a separate financial system. This separate financial system's API requires two things, an auth_code and an access_token. The access_token must be updated every 60 minutes.

I have a refresh_token that I use to get a new access_token. This refresh_token expires every 365 days. As a result, I can simply reuse this refresh_token every time I request a new access_token.

My app is in the really early stages and doesn't require anything but a simple api post from the first system to kick off this process. This will eventually be built out to require my own sort of auth_token to access my django api.

`first system --> Django App --> Finance System`

https://developer.blackbaud.com/skyapi/docs/authorization/auth-code-flow/tutorial

Process:

I currently have a celery task that runs in the background every 55 minutes. This task gathers the new access_token and recreates my `.env` file with the new access_token.

I have a separate celery task that runs an ETL pipeline and requires the access_token to post to the financial systems api.

Comment: "Am I approaching this all wrong?"—probably. A token that needs to be refreshed every 6 minutes probably doesn't belong in an environment variable. Is this a [refresh token](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/)? Typically that would be associated with a specific user and therefore not be cached server-side at all: it would be cached, and refreshed, _client-side_. Please [edit] your question and provide more information about your token refresh requirements.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I added some detail around the refresh_token and access_token situation. Thanks for the link you sent, that has some good information. I've never really had to deal with an API that required this level of authentication, so I really appreciate the assist. Also if you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: @Chris, your earlier comment makes a lot more sense after a good night of sleep. haha. It would make WAY more sense to tie the access_token to a user profile. I'm going to head down that route for now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you've got a new approach to try out. If you want to use your old one, consider using a [data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) (database, in-memory key-value store, whatever) to store your key instead of an environment variable. That's probably a better fit.

Comment: Interesting! I'll check that out. Thanks again!